# How to repeat a single sound without pause by the background audio player?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I need background player to play a single track in a cycle without a pause between end and beginning. How could I implement it?

I have tried to implement it by AudioPlayerAgent but it is not able to remove pause which is short but stay here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using XNA Library?

```
Song song = Content.Load<Song>("BackgroundMusic");
MediaPlayer.Play(song);
MediaPlayer.Volume = 0.5f;
MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
```

I am not sure it works as you want though.

Comment: It doesn't play in background. I need a sound to be played when application is not active.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should look at the BackgroudAudioPlayer.

More informations and some examples are available right here =>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsphonetrainingcourse_musicplayerlab_topic2.aspx

Maybe you could use the event PlayStateChanged to launch again the same music.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The question was about backgroundaudioplayer usage but the main question how to remove pause between end and beginning of a track. Restart playing from the StateChanged handler doesn't  solve the issue.